# Theming Wijmo Data Viz widgets (2.1.6) with Knockout Js

Tags: knockout.js, wijmo

I need to theme the gauges, charts, etc based on user settings in the Wijmo gadgets. I was hoping they would work the same with css as the [other widgets theming](http://wijmo.com/demo/themes/), but it doesn't (because it's drawing an svg). I'm using Knockout js and I see that I can bind each property. Anyone have a good approach to solving this? I have a few cooking at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [an answer from Chris Bannon](http://wijmo.com/topic/handling-browser-resizing-with-knockoutjs/#post-6710) and will leave this question for other's information.

See his [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr2qz/14/) for a good example and a way forward. I'm looking forward to the next release.